# pandas .drop(columns=[]) is returning KeyError when columns are in the csv and dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, drop

I'm trying to import market data from a csv to run some backtests.

[image: The csv is structured like:]

I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("30mindata.csv")
df = df.drop(columns=['Volume', 'NumberOfTrades', 'BidVolume', 'AskVolume'])
print(df)
```

I'm getting the error:

> KeyError: "['Volume', 'NumberOfTrades', 'BidVolume', 'AskVolume'] not found in axis"

When I remove the line of code containing `drop()` the dataframe prints as follows:

```
            Date       Time     Open     High      Low     Last   Volume   NumberOfTrades   BidVolume   AskVolume
0      2018/2/18   14:00:00  2734.50  2741.00  2734.00  2739.75     5304             2787        2299        3005
1      2018/2/18   14:30:00  2739.75  2741.00  2739.25  2740.25     1402              815         648         754
2      2018/2/18   15:00:00  2740.25  2743.50  2739.25  2742.00     4536             2301        2074        2462
3      2018/2/18   15:30:00  2742.25  2744.75  2742.25  2744.00     4102             1826        1949        2153
4      2018/2/18   16:00:00  2744.00  2744.25  2742.25  2742.25     2492             1113        1551         941
...          ...        ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...              ...         ...         ...
59074  2023/2/17   10:30:00  4076.25  4088.00  4076.00  4086.50    92507            54379       44917       47590
59075  2023/2/17   11:00:00  4086.50  4090.50  4079.25  4081.00   107233            67968       55784       51449
59076  2023/2/17   11:30:00  4081.00  4090.50  4079.50  4088.25   171507            92705       86022       85485
59077  2023/2/17   12:00:00  4088.00  4089.00  4085.25  4086.00    41032            17210       21176       19856
59078  2023/2/17   12:30:00  4086.25  4088.00  4085.25  4085.75     5164             2922        2818        2346
```

I have another file that uses this exact form of `pd.read_csv()` and then `df.drop(columns=[])` which works just fine. I tried `df.loc[:, 'Volume']` and got the same `KeyError` saying `'Volume' was not found in the axis`. I really don't understand how the labels aren't in the dataframe when they get output correctly without the `.drop()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you have blank spaces in the name of your columns.

Try removing those spaces doing this...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("30mindata.csv")
df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]
```

Then try to drop the columns as before